Can't Connect to Couchbase Server
I'm trying to integrate Couchbase with Azure Data Factory (ADF), but I'm encountering issues when attempting to establish a connection.
Here's the JSON configuration I'm using for my linked service:
{
"name": "Couchbase",
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
"properties": {
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "Couchbase",
    "typeProperties": {
        "connectionString": "Server=couchbases://cb.igko7dcwqaggfl3c.cloud.couchbase.com;Port=11207;AuthMech=1;CredString=[{\"user\": \"admin\", \"pass\":\"MyPassword\"}];"
    }
}

Error details:
Error code 9603
Details ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][Couchbase] (130) Can't connect to the Couchbase server.
Activity ID 9b358cca-2144-409c-8763-b7e6a574470f

What I've tried:

Server Name and Port:


Used couchbases://cb.igko7dcwqaggfl3c.cloud.couchbase.com as the server name.
Set the port to 11207.
Used not secured connection (server: couchbase://cb.igko7dcwqaggfl3c.cloud.couchbase.com, port 11210)


CredString Format:


Inputted the CredString as:
[{"user": "admin", "pass":"YourPassword"}, {"user": "secondUser", "pass":"YourPassword"}]

Also tried without the array brackets:
{"user": "admin", "pass":"YourPassword"}



Allowed Ip's


Allow All Addresses

If I use credentials in .NET SDK, everything works:
var endpoint = "couchbases://cb.igko7dcwqaggfl3c.cloud.couchbase.com";
var username = "admin";
var password = "YourPassword#";



I've not used Azure Data Factory, but I noticed that the credential string asks for "user" and "pass" (which matches the documentation). But in Couchbase, it's usually "username" and "password". This is a total guess, but maybe try that? Also, not sure if that's the correct port or not. Could you try 18091, or possibly try omitting the port? (again, total shot in the dark here)

Unfortunately, I tried to connect in this way and I get the same error

According to the docs, doesn't the type property need to be set to Couchbase instead of Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices?

Try connection from the location of the client to couchbase with SDK Doctor
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/sdk/sdk-doctor.html


In your endpoint you have provided server name as couchbases://cb.igko7dcwqaggfl3c.cloud.couchbase.com but while connecting to ADF you mentioned couchbase://cb.igko7dcwqaggfl3c.cloud.couchbase.com once cross check your endpoint along with that check your credentials once, that may be the reason to get above error.
Provide your connection string as below format:
"connectionString": "Server=<server>; Port=<port>;AuthMech=1;CredString=[{\"user\": \"JSmith\", \"pass\":\"access123\"}, {\"user\": \"Admin\", \"pass\":\"simba123\"}];"

For more information you can refer to the MS document.
